# How to reference the output from AWS provider plan in Kubernetes provider plan?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I have 2 directories:

- `aws/`
- `k8s/`

In the `aws/` dir, I've provisioned an EKS cluster and EKS node group (among other things) using the Terraform AWS provider. That's been applied and everything looks good there.

When trying to then create a Kubernetes provider plan in `k8s/` and create a Persistent Volume resource it requires the EBS volume ID.

[Terraform Kubernetes Persistent Volume Resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/persistent_volume.html)

How do I get the EBS volume ID from the other `.tfstate` file from a Kubernetes provider plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understand it, you want to reference resource from another state file. To do that you can use the following example:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "aws_state" {
  backend = "remote"

  config = {
  organization = "hashicorp"
  workspaces = {
    name = "state-name"
  }
}
```

}

And once you have data resources available you can reference ebs volume in the following way:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.aws_state.outputs.ebs_volume_id
```

Remember to create an output called `ebs_volume_id`